# How to make certain rows of datagridview read only and other editable in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform that contains datagrid view which contains some data which is loaded when i run my application but suppose during running user can add new row to this datagridview but would not be able to edit the existing entries of datagridview then how to do that.

I have tried setting readonly property of columns to true but it makes everthing non editable, i have also tried this :-

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in cevnt.Properties)
{
DataGridViewComboBoxCell propertyType1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();                    
DataGridViewTextBoxCell propertyName1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();                    
propertyName1.Value = entry.Key.ToString();
propertyName1.ReadOnly = true;   int index = 
propertyTypeList.IndexOf(entry.Value.ToString());                   
propertyType1.Items.AddRange(propertyTypeList);
  if(index != -1)
    {
       propertyType1.DisplayMember = propertyTypeList[index];
    }         
   else
    {
         propertyType1.DisplayMember = string.Empty;
    }
    customEventPropertiesDgv.Rows.Add(entry.Key.ToString());
    customEventPropertiesDgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1] = propertyType1;
    customEventPropertiesDgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true;
 }
```

Here i am setting individual cell readonly property to true.But it didn't worked.

My datagridview that contains existing data which i want to be non editable but when user writes something to last row it must be editable.
   [image]

Comment: `DataGridViewRow` class has a `Readonly` property. Try setting all existing rows to read only.

Comment: That setup looks like a [PropertyGrid control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx#usingpropgrid_topic1). You should have it available in your ToolBox (All Windows Controls or with a search). You could considered using this class, adding some simple means to add a new value to the grid.